# Ubuntu 19.04 Software Center - which apps are official / legitimate?

Tags: software-center

I've just installed Ubuntu 19.04 and I'm installing all my normal sofware.

I've noticed that many apps have mutilple versions/sources.  How would I tell which ones are official?

Some are from ubuntu-disco-universe and others from Snap Store.  Some have a developer listed and others don't.  Some packages have different developers for each version.

For example I have these two options for kdenlive:

```
kdenlive 
 - Version: 16.12 
 - Developer: j-b-m 
 - Source: Snap Store


kdenlive
 - Version: 4:18.12.3a-0ubuntu1
 - Developer: ...BLANK...
 - Source: ubuntu-disco-universe
```

Edit:  I'm specifically trying to avoid potential malware or trusted software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Software Center includes software from three (mostly) independent sources:

- The [Ubuntu (.deb) repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com). Your Ubuntu system is mostly made of synchronized deb packages from here. All deb packages from the Ubuntu repositories are "official" and supported here. Deb packages from other sources are not supported here.
- The [Ubuntu Snap Store](https://snapcraft.io/store). This is a newer system of packaging optimized for phones and devices, but can be installed on Desktops too. Snaps are supported by whoever created the snap. Some snaps are created by quite reputables folks (Canonical, Snapcrafters), others are experiments.
- Debs and Snaps that you have downloaded and installed yourself from other sources. These are (obviously) not official, and are supported only by wherever you downloaded the software from.

In your specific case, look at the Versions:

- 16.12 / Snap Store
- 18.12.3 / ubuntu-disco-universe

I recommend the ubuntu-disco-universe (deb from the Ubuntu repositories), as it's version will match the rest of KDE's debs on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Recently kdenlive dropped support for snap. So I would recommend you install using ppa.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kdenlive/kdenlive-stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install kdenlive
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use flatpak. The Kdenlive flatpak is updated to the latest version.

The easy way is to install flatpak support for Gnome Software with: `sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-flatpak`
Then search for kdenlive and make sure to select the flatpak version.